# What is the fastest way to send data over LAN?

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, networking, tcp

Now I am using Socket `SendFile` API, to send file or it part over any networks. Can I make this process faster over the `lan`? I know about programs like [TeraCopy](http://codesector.com/teracopy) that makes coping file over LAN much faster (some people say about 2x speed up) in comparison with windows explorer coping that is using `CopyFile` API (I think). I don't know how they do this. Could you advice me?

Comment: You'll find that TeraCopy probably still uses the Win32 `FileCopy` library. There is no easy way to improve the network point-to-point, and I'd trust the Windows/Samba developers to have optimized their low level code to do this well. The best you can hope for is optimizing your file queuing.

Comment: @Xenolightning after some searhing a see that there are a lot of faster file trasfer then standart TCP for different condition: for a lot of small files - first, for large files over high speed network with high latancy - second, for large files win high speed networks with low latancy - third..still searhing...

Comment: Well you have two questions, "Can I make this process faster over lan?" the obvious answer is `Yes`. Then you ask about how TeraCopy works, which is what I used as the context for your 'real' question. Maybe you revise your question to something like "I want to transfer files over a network, how do best do this to maximize the speed of the transfer?"

Answer (score 2):

You could compress the data on the fly, then decompress it after you have send it over the network.

[GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is nice for this sort of thing, and basic compressing/decompressing examples are provided.

Compressing will of course make you take a CPU performance hit, but you will have to transfer less data, allowing for short transfer time. The nice thing about this library is that the compression works with streams. So you could stream over network without having to wait for the whole file to compress.

Comment: This wouldn't work unless you had another daemon running at the destination to decompress the stream. Otherwise you end up having to decompress the stream before calling the `CopyFile` API. Or worst case scenario, writing the compressed file to the destination, then having to read and write it back to decompress it.

Comment: You are right, but the question is not very precise on how the transfer should happen. So I made assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

One way of speeding up file copying would be to do it over UDP instead of TCP. The problem then, is to implement error checking (As UDP does not guarantee that a packet arrives intact, or in order).

Windows explorer file copy is slow because it opens each file individually, copies it, and then closes it (At least as far as I'm aware).

Your question doesn't really give any code, so it's a bit difficult to answer 'correctly'.

Comment: UDP is a terrible way to copy files, the overhead will far outway any perceived savings in handshaking etc. Files are sequential streams of binary data, exactly what TCP is designed to do.

Comment: @Ashigore: For writing files it doesn't matter what order the packets arrive in, so that might save on queueing at the receiving end if the packets arrive out of order. I do agree that the costs probably outweigh the benefits though.

Comment: Here what i found http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP-based_Data_Transfer_Protocol it is based on UDP like some others protocols optimized for large files transfers  over high speed wide area networks, that are more effectife in this than TCP. But it is bad idead to write such protocol on udp yourself in some general app... too many work.